# Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted when AppPool is recycled

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, websocket, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a .net Core application hosted on IIS.
The application initializes **WebSocketServer**, by adding a wrapper class as a **HostedService**.
The hosted service execute the **Start()** method seen below on its **StartAsync()** and the **Destroy()** method on its **StopAsync()** method.
The problem that whenever the related application pool is recycled - the error in the title appears ("Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"). It happens because there is a new working process that starts-up and trying to use the ports of the socket before there is a shutdown of the current Working process which still use the socket with the same ports.
I'm trying to find a way of avoiding that situation, programmatically or by configuration.
Here is my code of the HostedService:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;

namespace XXXX
{
    public class WebsocketServerWrapper
    {
        // Thats an websocket server , he will host our service as web socket service.
        private static WebSocketServer wss;
        private static readonly object LockObject = new object();

        public static IConfiguration Config { get; set; }

        public static bool IsCreated()
        {
            return wss != null;
        }

        public static bool HasChannels()
        {
            if(IsCreated())
            {
                return wss.WebSocketServices.Paths.Any();
            }

            return false;
        }

        public static bool IsListening()
        {
            if (wss != null)
            {
                return wss.IsListening;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public static void AddChannel(string channel)
        {
            if (wss.WebSocketServices.Paths.Any((path) => path == channel) == false)
            {
                    wss.AddWebSocketService(channel,() => new <class that treats the socket behaviour itself>(Config));
            }
        }

        public static bool Start()
        {
            wss.Start();

            if (IsListening())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool Destroy()
        {
             var isDestroyed = false;

            if(IsCreated())
            {
                removeWebSocketServices();
                wss.Stop();
                wss = null;
                isDestroyed = true;
            }

            return isDestroyed;
        }
        internal static void removeWebSocketServices()
        {
            var channels = wss?.WebSocketServices?.Paths?.ToList() ?? null;
            if (channels != null)
            {
                channels.ForEach(channel => { wss.RemoveWebSocketService(channel); channel = null; });
            }
        }

        public static bool CreateWSSServer()
        {
            bool isCreationSucceeded = false;

            if(!IsCreated())
            {
                lock(LockObject)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var wssUrl = Config.GetValue<string>(<WebsocketServerUrl adress>);

                        wss = new WebSocketServer($"ws://{wssUrl}");
                        isCreationSucceeded = true;
                    }
                    catch (WebSocketException wse)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(wse);
                        return isCreationSucceeded;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(e);
                        return isCreationSucceeded;
                    }
                }
            }

            isCreationSucceeded = true;

            return isCreationSucceeded;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `The hosted service execute the Start() method seen below on its StartAsync() and the Destroy() method on its StopAsync() method. `Can you share the code where you use `Destroy()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to that scenario (edited it in the question) - it turns out that the scenario of the server starts-up with new worker process before the "old" worker process shutdown  is not rare - there is a parameter in the application pool under **Recycling** => **Disable Overlapped Recycle** - if it set to true (it is false by default), then the startup with new Working process will occur only after the current worker process will shut-down